# The stack frame destruction

Tags: assembly, masm

There are a lot of topics regarding this subject but I couldn't find an answer for what I was looking for in all the topics I found.

My actual question is:

When we enter into a procedure, we use the function prologues and epilogue (ENTER and LEAVE instructions) in order to keep the program running correctly without any leaks.

Suppose you want 2 local variables in your proecedure. You would decrease ESP by 8 to default the alignment to be 4 bytes (DWORD). In the end of the proecedure you would like to **DESTROY/RELEASE** these variables so you must set ESP to be EBP.

My question is, how does the change of the ESP address to be equal to the EBP address destroy/release the local variables? What happens after we call the RET? How the stack frame is destroyed?

Comment: What exactly does "destroy" and "release" mean in your mind? Are you imagining little janitors walking through your RAM, picking up small, old variables and releasing them back into the wild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question: well the `ESP` is a pointer to the top of the stack so if you add 8 to the `ESP` at the end of a procedure you are decreasing the stack. the memory stored in the local fields is not in the stack anymore so it can be changed as you want. Second question: the `RET` command does two things: it returns the control to the main program but in a more technical way - it reads the number from the top of the stack and writes it to the `EIP` register which is the instruction pointer.
It is also worth knowing that the `CALL` instruction does two things - it pushes the next order's address to the stack, and then it jumps to the procedure - this means the `RET` knows where to jump back to

Answer (score 2):

The epilogue of a function looks like this:

```
mov %esp, %ebp
pop %ebp
ret
```

or (in x86, where leave does the same thing as the first 2 lines above)

```
leave
ret
```

Answering your question:

-in the first part of the instruction leave, we set de %ebp to be equal to %esp

-as we call "ret", the value of PC (program counter) is set to the address of instruction next to "call" instrucution, by popping the top of the stack.

-the stack frame is "destroyed" as we set the new value to %esp ( %esp + 4)